# how many files does a forum generate ?? (for hosting issues)

Tags: php, hosting, forum

i am still looking for the appropriate host ... but all the unlimited space unlimited bandwidth hosts .... have a limited number of files (inodes) ... usually 50,000 so my question is ... in the forums for example ... does every thread generate a new file or not ?? mostly on smf .... and if any one know the same issue for a question and answers website too ... thanks in advance .. peace

Comment: Most bulletin board / forum scripts store the messages (and "threads") in the database. So it's usually not an issue. And even if file/image uploads are permitted, you're likely overestimating. (But as alternative: there are many free forum hosting services, which are a good idea to avoid micromanaging it yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't generate anything except cache, just limit attachments that users can post and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the forum software - most of them keep the discussions in a database, so there would be no new files generated by this activity. A possible exception: user-uploaded attachments might be stored on-disk, but this could be overcome by using external image hosting services (e.g. Imgur).

Some forums have built-in caching mechanisms with file storage, but this could be a) limited to a given size/file count, or b) turned off altogether.

In general, the number of actual files is independent of the content - and doesn't change much; in fact, it would be possible (albeit impractical) to have all the code stored in a single file, and generate all your pages from there.

Answer (score 0):

Most forums (maybe even all) are going to be database driven and not file driven.  Some, as webarto alluded to, may store attachments in the file system and others may store them in the database.  Some may even support storing them in Amazon's S3 storage which would mean you wouldn't have to worry about going over the limit.

So the only files you'll have on the system will be the actual forum code.  Depending on the forum and the language this can vary greatly but you'll be well under 50,000.

Comment: i am making a relatively big website where the forum will be just a component .... this is why i am worried ...

Comment: I still think you'll be well within your bounds.  50,000 files are a lot of files and you can always use some cheaper mechanism for storing things like images and static content if you need to reduce the number of files.  You'd probably need to be generating files via a computer algorithm to reach that number.  A website of 50,000 non-generated files would be a nightmare to maintain.